# Как реализовать добавление нескольких значений параметру при add/edit объекта

Tags: java, sql, jsp, spring-mvc, dao

Подскажите реализацию добавления нескольких значений параметру при add/edit объекта. 
Использую простенькие jsp, Spring MVC, паттерн ДАО и JDBS для взаимодействия с БД. реализация будет на Java (еще не реализовано, но в планах именно такая реализация — более сложные вещи не рекомендуется)

Есть книга, у которой может быть несколько жанров.
в БД есть 3 таблички: книг, жанров, и связки книга_жанры где указываем какие жанры могут быть у книги.

Нужно реализовать через веб-интерфейс (обычные jsp) добавление и редактирование книги, а именно: при создании указать название, цену и ее жанры. и возможность редактирования к каким жанрам книга может принадлежать.

А пока не совсем понимаю, как корректнее реализовать добавление жанров к книге или удалить не нужные жанры (имеется в виду из связки книга_жанры)
начиная с тыкания в браузере по кнопкам и заканчивая запросом/вставкой/апдейтом/мерджом в базу)

Можете дать направление пожалуйста?

Comment: На данный момент в качестве праймари кей для таблицы книга_жанры выступает комбинация PK(id_book, id_genre) третьего поля в ней нет.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что спрашиваете, слишком общие вопросы, но попробуем разобраться. 1. http://www.javaportal.ru/java/tutorial/tutorialJDBC/preparedstatement.html вам понятно как работать с базой через statement ? Напишите sql запросы здесь для добавления книги, добавления жанра и добавление в таблицу книга + жанр. Таблица номер 3 содержит 2 поля - book_id и genre_id.

Comment: @Adrenal1ne
Да, я работала с этим.
По факту, я уже  реализовала как-то добавление обьекта таким образом, но этот обьект был проще, вроде добавление записи в таблицу сотрудников ,например, через джсп указали ФИО и должность(только одна должность) контроллер обработал это событие, вызвал нужные методы и через preparedstatement заинсертили в базу.

до меня не доходит как корректно реализовать добавление/объекта , если значений у параметра может быть несколько. 
-как лучше отобразить добавление жанров к книге используя стандартные элементы, и обработать эти данные для передачи в контроллер,

Comment: - какова будет процедура занесения такого рода данных непосредственно в БД (писать сам запрос не нужно, но куда что в каком порядке вставлять было бы неплохо)
- может в контроллере как-то по особенному это обрабатывать.
как я понимаю то в POJO будет какой-нить экземпляр линкед или аррей листа, как атрибут, что будет хранить жанры книги, хотя в самой таблице Книга этих данных нет.

Comment: Например ,как вы видите жизненный цикл такого функционала, но с описанием тех.деталей реализации

Comment: . до меня не доходит как корректно реализовать добавление/объекта , если значений у параметра может быть несколько.----------------------------------------------------------------------------Опять всё смутно понял, но чтобы передать много параметров в запрос вы можете создать класс, аналогичный таблице в БД, и передавать в методах этот объект, а не кусу стрингов, листов или массивом.

Comment: а разве правильно создавать класс для таблицы, которая реализует связь один ко многим?

Comment: А ккакой у вас класс один ко многим ?

Comment: Тут немного неправильно выразилась,  таблица книга_жанры вспомогательная для реализации отношения многие-ко-многим, зачем для нее делать класс?
у на данным момент есть класс-модель для объектов Жанр и для объектов Книга