# Реализация создания и редактирования обьекта с множественным атрибутом. Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

вот мой вопрос предудущий: [Как реализовать добавление нескольких значений параметру при add/edit объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685983/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-add-edit-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0)

он был немного некорректный. Книга может иметь несколько жанров, и их связми хранятся в отдельно таблице рилейшнов.

подскажите алгоритм добавления этих жанров при создании книги , как это правильно организовать в jsp-контроллер, 
и как правильно организовать и обработать редактирование этого поля, тоже в jsp-контроллер,
Спасибо

php и JS ни разу не пользовалась - желательно без них, только с синтаксисом jsp.